# T-SQL, select rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, ssms

as shown in the screenshot, for different id, I want to select all rows that have common updateTime. For example here, all three IDs have common updateTime 9:30:02 and 9:30:04. Therefore, I want to select the 3rd and 4th rows (for id 211709), 6th and 8th rows (for id 301801), 9th and 10th rows (for id 931801), I want to select all these 6 rows. What sql code should I write? Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: Anyone, any solution? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to return only update times that are common for *all* IDs, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE UpdateTime IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT UpdateTime
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY UpdateTime
    HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.Id) FROM MyTable c WHERE c.UpdateTime = UpdateTime) = COUNT(DISTINCT Id)
)
```

If you wonder what the `HAVING` clause does - for every UpdateTime you checking if number of IDs with this UpdateTime equals total number of IDs.

Comment: Thank you guys, a great help!

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you all update times that occur more than once

```
Select UpdateTime
From MyTable
Group By UpdateTime
Having Count (*) > 1
```

Use this as a sub query

```
Select * 
From MyTable
Where UpdateTime IN
(
    Select UpdateTime
    From MyTable
    Group By UpdateTime
    Having Count (*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Stupid question... will `9:30:00` appear on here, since it has a `Count > 1`? OP is only look for `9:30:02` and `9:30:04`

Comment: 9:30:00 should NOT show here because id 931801 doesn't have that updateTime

Comment: Any solutions? Thanks!